# Включение экрана программно

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как включить экран устройства программно, используя Service.
Использую `WakeLock`, но там есть `Depricated` методы, и работает не на всех устройствах.

```
WakeLock PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
```

Прочитал, что можно использовать `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, но для этого нужно `activity`, а у меня service:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Костыли, но может вам все такие использовать активити, которую вы запустите из сервиса, включите экран и завершите активити?

Comment: да, как и выше сказали, я в сервисе просто создавал прозрачную маленькую вьюшку и показывал.